# is the fourier transform of $\cosh (ax)=\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega-ia)+\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega+ia)$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Is the fourier transform F of $\cosh (ax)$: $ F(\cosh (ax))=\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega-ia)+\sqrt \frac{\pi}{2} \delta(\omega+ia)$

This is the answer wolfram alpha gives. I am looking up the meaning of a complex delta and can't find anything. So I think wolfram is just spitting out nonsense. Is there any meaning to a complex valued delta function?

Comment: Why do you need the fourier transform of coshx ? Out of curiosity?

Comment: Someone asked about this on reddit.com/math. He linked to a blog where someone claimed to have derived the residue of the delta function.  I've spent some time reading into this to see if there is anything there of substance. https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/389n2g/does_the_dirac_delta_function_have_a_residue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cosh$ is a divergent integral. So normally you would say it has no fourier transform. However it is possible to assign consistent transformations to divergent integrals (like $1/t$ $1/t^2$)

$\delta(\omega-ia)$ means you need to insert $ia$ where you see $\omega$ in the integral, which indeed will result in $\cosh x$ if you were to apply the inverse transform integral.

This representation clearly does not make sense, however it is consistent and if you make calculations with it, it will work out in the end.

Comment: So you just treat $ia$ as a real number?  Normally you think of the Dirac delta as though it were integrated over the real number line. This is a little weird. I will try to do the inverse transform by hand when I get a chance to see how it works out.  I don't have much time at the moment.

Comment: There are many weird results in fourier transformation that arise due to divergent integrals. Pretty much the foundation of $$\int ^\infty _{-\infty}e^{-ikx}dx=2\pi \delta(k)$$ says that if you sum infinitely many cosines with all values of frequencies, you'll end up with a delta function.

Comment: Should I use that representation of the delta when I check this?

Comment: I don't see how that would help. $$\int\delta(\omega-ia)e^{i\omega x}d\omega=e^{i (ia) x}\int\delta(\omega-ia)d\omega$$ Again, this does not really make sense, but it is consistent.

Comment: I was thinking you would get something like $\int e^{i (a-\omega)}$ but thats integrating with respect to the wrong variable.. I need to think about this on my own for a bit when I can really do the work. Thanks