# Why is the Fourier transform of $\tan(t)$ not $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc(\frac{\pi \omega}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}$

I was curious why Wolfram Alpha does not give a Fourier transform for $\tan(t)$ when it does provide one for $\tanh(t)$. [According to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fourier%20transform%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22tanh%28t%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22w%22) $\mathcal{F}[\tanh(t)] = i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csch(\frac{\pi \omega}{2}) $. This is all well and good, however using the fact that $\mathcal{F}[g(a t)] = \frac{1}{|a|}\hat{g}(\frac{t}{a})$, we could easily show that $\mathcal{F}[\tanh(t)] = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc(\frac{\pi \omega}{2})$. Note that,
$-i \tanh(i t) = \tan(t)$ and $i \csch(i \omega) =\csc(\omega)$. Therefore, setting $a = i$ the following formula holds.

$-i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 |a|}} \csch(\frac{\pi \omega}{2 a}) =-i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2|i|}} \csch(\frac{\pi \omega}{2 i}) =-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\csc( \frac{-\pi \omega}{2}) = \csc(\frac{\pi \omega}{2}) $

[This question implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311520/is-the-fourier-transform-of-cosh-ax-sqrt-frac-pi2-delta-omega-ia-s) that this sort of manipulation is allowed. Have I voilated some underlying integrability assumption where this is not a valid operation? Or does Wolfram Alpha have some oversight.

As context I was working a derivation of the fact $\sech(\pi t)$ is its own Fourier transform, and the method works for $\tan(t)$ as well. I was a bit surprised that Wolfram Alpha does not have $\tan(t)$, leading me to question my method.

Comment: Can you edit your question to detail the sentence *(...) we could easily show (...)*

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have added more details and fixed a sign error.

Comment: This FT diverges, $\tan x$ has poles on the real line. Even with a principal value prescription to remove the poles, the remaining function is still periodic, and hence it's FT is a sum of appropriately weighted delta peaks. In what sense do you expect the above result to hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan(t)=\frac{i \left(e^{-i t}-e^{i t}\right)}{e^{i t}+e^{-i t}}\tag{1}$$

so

$$\mathcal{F}_t[\tan(t)](\omega)=i \left(\mathcal{F}_t\left[\frac{e^{-i t}}{e^{i t}+e^{-i t}}\right](\omega)-\mathcal{F}_t\left[\frac{e^{i t}}{e^{i t}+e^{-i t}}\right](\omega)\right)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \csc\left(\frac{\pi \omega}{2}\right)\tag{2}$$

(see [Wolfram Alpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=i%20%28FourierTransform%5BE%5E%28-I%20t%29%2F%28E%5E%28-I%20t%29%20%2B%20E%5E%28I%20t%29%29%2C%20t%2C%20%5C%5BOmega%5D%5D%20-%20FourierTransform%5BE%5E%28I%20t%29%2F%28E%5E%28-I%20t%29%20%2B%20E%5E%28I%20t%29%29%2C%20t%2C%20%5C%5BOmega%5D%5D%29)).